# Finding the probability of the difference of two discrete random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have the following problem:

[image]

I am asked to find $$P(|X-Y| < 1)$$

My attempt at finding this probability was:
$$P(|X-Y| < 1)=$$
$$P((X-Y) < 1)$$
$$P(-(X-Y) < 1)$$
$$P(-(X-Y) < 1 <(X-Y))$$

I was a little confused on where to go from there, so I got the PMF in a table:
[image]

However, that really didn't help me. I looked at the solution, and it was given that
$$P(|X-Y| < 1)=P(|X-Y| = 0)=P(X=Y)$$

However, I don't understand how 
$$P(|X-Y| < 1)=P(|X-Y| = 0)$$

Comment: The relation holds since the only few values for $(X, Y)$ with non-zero value for the PMF are integers (i.e. ordered pairs of integers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $X$ and $Y$ are integers, $Z=|X-Y|$ is integer too. From the definition of absolute value we can assume that $Z\ge 0$. Thus, $Z$ can take values $0,1,2,\ldots$ However, from $Z<1$, we can conclude that $Z$ can be only $0$.

Comment: ahh I see, so just because of the fact that X and Y are discrete, that means the only possible values for |X - Y| < 1 would be 0?

Comment: Yes. In integer realm one can use transition $a>b \Rightarrow a\ge b+1$. If you use this rule to your findings $-1<X-Y<1$, you will get $0\le X-Y \le 0$, which means $X-Y=0$